# Firestore Security Rules - Missing or insufficient permission, but I have written them

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get an specific document in a public collection, but I am getting the error "Missing or insufficient permission".

But, I think I wrote this good:

```
match /posts/{userId}/userPosts/{postId} {
  allow read: if isSignedIn() && request.query.limit <= 10;
  allow write, update, delete: if false;
  
  match /likes/{document=**} {
    allow read: if isSignedIn();
    allow write: if false;
  }
  
  match /comments/{document=**} {
    allow read: if isSignedIn();
    allow write: if false;
  }
}
```

With this code, the security rules works fine:

```
  const query = firestore
    .collection("posts")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("userPosts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .startAfter(startAfter);

  const querySnapshot = await query.limit(limit).get();
```

But... with this one, I am getting the error:

```
  const myPostRef = firestore
    .collection("posts")
    .doc(userId)
    .collection("userPosts")
    .doc(postId);

  const myPostDoc = await myPostRef.get();
```

Why I can't get a specific doc?

Comment: Are you sure ```request.query.limit``` *HAS* a value when you execute a simple ```.get()``` ?

Comment: Removing that was the problem! But... I need it. Any way to combine both rules?

Comment: Possibly an OR - something like "signed in AND (not-query OR limit<10)"

Comment: Are you certainly sending correct ```postId```?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to break your `allow read` rule into specific rules for queries and single documents:

```
allow list: if isSignedIn() && request.query.limit <= 10;
allow get: if isSignedIn();
```